# In Node.js Mongoose, I want to update each field...how can I do that?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

```
User.find({},function(err,docs){ 
            foreach(docs as d){
                d.name="apple";
                d.save();
            };
        });
```

This doesn't work! I get some "unique identifier" error. Can someone fix this for me?

Comment: not knowing anything about mongoose and only just today saw a demo of Node, perhaps giving all your docs the name "apple" is not right? Can you do `d.name="apple"+(i++);` and define `var i=0` before the foreach? Or are you talking about http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mongoose/lib/Mongoose/Intro.pod#_id

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're using foreach incorrectly. Try replacing the contents of your callback with this:

```
docs.forEach(function(elem, index, array) {
    elem.name = "apple";
    elem.save();
});
```

Check out the MDC for more information on [foreach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/foreach).

Comment: don't you mean forEach? Case matters in JS :)

Comment: You're right, nice catch! Answers are wiki style, so you could always fix little bugs like this, too.

Answer (score 0):

Does `d` have a unique index set? If so you will be unable to set the same thing for multiple instances.